# Sequel DB Connection PoolTimeout Error

Tags: mysql, ruby, jruby, sequel

I have been unable to determine what the cause of the following `Sequel::PoolTimeout` error is coming from in a Ruby script I have written:

```
Sequel::PoolTimeout: Sequel::PoolTimeout
             hold at /Users/username/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@all/gems/sequel-4.2.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:100
             hold at /Users/username/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@all/gems/sequel-4.2.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:93
      synchronize at /Users/username/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@all/gems/sequel-4.2.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:234
          execute at /Users/username/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@all/gems/sequel-4.2.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:258
          execute at /Users/username/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@all/gems/sequel-4.2.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:793
       fetch_rows at /Users/username/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@all/gems/sequel-4.2.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:671
             each at /Users/username/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@all/gems/sequel-4.2.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:143
    single_record at /Users/username/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@all/gems/sequel-4.2.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:583
     single_value at /Users/username/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@all/gems/sequel-4.2.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:591
              get at /Users/username/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@all/gems/sequel-4.2.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:250
           empty? at /Users/username/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@all/gems/sequel-4.2.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:153
            scrap at /Users/username/projectname/processers/get_category.rb:46
             each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1617
  each_with_index at org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:920
            scrap at /Users/username/projectname/processers/get_category.rb:44
            scrap at /Users/username/projectname/processers/get_category.rb:32
```

I have tried this with both MRI and JRuby with exactly the same results.

As per the instructions on the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) gem [here](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html), I have attempted to raise the `pool_timeout` limit as follows:

```
DB = Sequel.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost/project_db?user=USERNAME&password=PASSWD&max_connections=10&pool_timeout=120")
```

It seems as though the `max_connections` and `pool_timeout` may not be recognized, however I'm not seeing any other way to pass these args on into the connection.

The actual code that is in question here is:
`if DB[:products].where(url: url.to_s).empty?`

I have seen the code work just fine for a little bit, but without fail it fails either right away or after a couple minutes without any reproducibility in terms of when it occurs.  I am starting to suspect that this is a MySQL config issue or something causing the `localhost` DBMS to have some prolonged delays, although, again, I cannot manually reproduce a visible timeout that I can tell with manual queries, etc.

Any ideas on this issue as to why the timout would keep happening or, more particularly, how to resolve it either via feeding `Sequel` proper settings (perhaps I have a malformed arg list) or modifying MySQL's `/etc/my.cnf` for such a scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The Sequel jdbc adapter passes the connection string directly to JDBC, it doesn't parse out embedded options.  You need to do:

`DB = Sequel.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost/project_db?user=USERNAME&password=PASSWD", :max_connections=>10, :pool_timeout=>120)`